# Toolbar overlaps other content in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar, android-toolbar

I'm trying to develop an app using a custom toolbar and it overlaps the other content on screen. I have a recycler view that I'm using to show card views with text on them.

In the design view it seems to be okay and shows that the recycler view is below the toolbar and unobstructed.

[Android Studio Design view shows the toolbar not obstructing the recycler view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfmcm.png)

However, when launching the app, it clearly overlaps.

[The app is launched and the content is hidden behind the toolbar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DBVC.png)

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
\android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/purple_200"
android:elevation="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/back_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/back_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/inventory_menu"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/delete_icon"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_outline_24" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/delete_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_24"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

example_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">


<RelativeLayout
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Line1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Line 2"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>enter code here
```

Comment: more details in activity_main screen

Comment: Sorry, I just left out the closing tag for the layout in activity_main if that is what you were talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `CoordinatorLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` as the parent. Look at this [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout).

With `ConstraintLayout` released [you should not use](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html) `RelativeLayout`, as it's slower and less capable.

Note: `CoordinatorLayout` and `ConstraintLayout` are not same thing and have very different use cases.